# Any framework that can be used for development of mobile apps in Python?

Tags: python, android, ios

I have heard (from one of my friends) that python CANNOT be used in mobile application development. So even the simplest one (print something on the screen) like the following cannot run in iOS/android devices if I am using python to code :

```
x = 1
if x == 1:
    # indented four spaces
    print("x is 1.")
```

Is it true that there is any alternative/framework which allows coding in python but can run in mobile app say ios and android? (or is it true that python not useful to write apps for running in mobile devices ?)

Please give me some advice. Thanks a lot.

Comment: the code snippet runs on Pydroid

Answer (score 1):

Something very basic like a print statement can definitely run on mobile devices if you have the python interpreter and a way to run your script, however it is not ideal to use python for mobile app development(adding buttons, gui, etc.). But there are still frameworks in python like kivy and beeware that can be used to develop applications for android. Kivy helps create GUI for any platform, if you created one for android it will work on windows also. For more details you can just google mobile development in python